# Date comparison not working in classic asp

Tags: date, asp-classic, date-comparison

In my classic asp code, I want to compare two dates. I have this code:

```
response.Write(date())
response.Write("<br/>")
response.Write(Deadline)
response.Write("<br/>")
response.Write(date() > Deadline)
```

And it outputs:

```
6/18/2013
12/17/2002
False
```

It should be true though. Also the value of `Deadline` is a value passed in from a url parameter, so its a regular string format, not sure if that matters.

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't done ASP or VBScript in awhile, but if I remember, you can convert a string to a date using the `CDate` function. So:

```
response.Write(date() > CDate(Deadline))
```

should get you what you're looking for.